# SymmetricDS : ORA-12899: value too large for column SYM_NODE_GROUP_LINK.DATA_EVENT_ACTION

Tags: oracle, postgresql, symmetricds

I have 2 databases , 1 postgres (updated in corp-000.properties) and 1 oracle (updated in store-001.properties). I have followed and verified below steps,

1. `../bin/dbimport --engine corp-000 --format XML create_sample.xml`
2. `../bin/symadmin --engine corp-000 create-sym-tables`
3. `../bin/dbimport --engine corp-000 insert_sample.sql`
4. `../bin/dbimport --engine store-001 --format XML create_sample.xml`

When I try to start the `symmetricDS` nodes by executing .`./bin/sym --port 8080 --server` I am getting below error,

```
ORA-12899: value too large for column SYM_NODE_GROUP_LINK.DATA_EVENT_ACTION
```

Have I missed any step ?

Comment: Try to change the datatype of the column SYM_NODE_GROUP_LINK.DATA_EVENT_ACTION to `VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)`

Comment: What are the config settings for Oracle in store-001.properties?

Comment: Changing the datatype to VARCHAR2(1 CHAR) solved the issue. Thanks for the help Tejash and Boris